# keycloak.protect() node js probleme CORS

Tags: node.js, express, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I have a problem with keycloak.protect(), I can't access my "/secured" route. Indeed, when I try to access it from my frontend, I have the CORS blocking me. However, I made sure with app.use(cors()) to allow everything. I also tested if I can get my token id from my frontend (I get it fine.) Do you have any idea what could be blocking?

My code to illustrate my point:

**index.ts**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import KeycloakConnect from 'keycloak-connect';

const session = require('express-session');
const Keycloak = KeycloakConnect;

const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mysecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

const keycloak = new Keycloak({store: memoryStore});

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: "/logout",
  admin: "/"
}));


app.use(cors());

app.get('/service/public', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

app.get('/secured', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

app.get('/service/admin', keycloak.protect('realm:admin'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'admin'});
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

**keycloak.json**

```
{
  "realm": "QRCoffee",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "QRCoffee",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

**Error CORS**

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/QRCoffee/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=QRCoffee&state=7321400d-3c51-4c53-8c9a-100101239845&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fsecured%3Fauth_callback%3D1&scope=openid&response_type=code' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/secured') from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

- I opened the corns to all the url : ok
- I tried to get the keycloak tokens from my front : ok
- I tried to open the keycloak side cores
- I tried to access a route without keycloak.protect() = No problem, I can access it fine
- I am well connected on the front side to keycloak.

I would like to access my /secured route when I am connected to keycloak.